# Разбор протокола

Tags: php

Привет!
Необходимо написать программу для разбора пакетов данных протокола, которые шлёт терминал ГЛОНАСС.

Возможно ли реализовать на PHP прослушивание порта и разбор пакета приходящего на порт? Или лучше на другом языке?

Comment: Я делал, можно, но лучше использовать что-то многопоточное или заморочиться с LibEvent в PHP

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать можно ([Сокеты PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sockets.php), [Примеры](http://php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php)). Для начала и простоты можно сделать на PHP. В будущем желательно использовать что-то другое. С другой стороны сейчас все больше людей настойчиво утверждает, что PHP силен во всем, но лично я в этом сильно сомневаюсь и такие специфичные вещи продолжаю делать на других языках, хоть и 99% времени работаю с PHP.